# Bifurcation diagram Problem number 3.3.1 c from Strogatz

Tags: graphing-functions, nonlinear-system

The question essentially asks the reader to draw a bifurcation diagram of the function $$n˙ ≈ pn/(n + 1) − n$$. The answer in the solution manual is:
[image]

But the graph of the function for negative p is

[image]
In the neighborhood of a negative fixed point we can see that if the particle displaces towards a more negative value, the value of the function becomes positive, pushing it towards the right side, where it gets pushed to the left side due to the negative value of the function there. Thus it seems like a stable fixed point as opposed to the one mentioned in the book solution.